# Access policy for AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Context: We will be setting up several EC2 instances of which some will have sensitive customer information. Because of the sensitive information each IAM user can only have access to their own EC2 instance.

Being new to aws I'm trying to understand access policy, specific to EC2 instances. I've read the documentation and it appears to me that I am able to grant an IAM user specific access to its EC2 instance that user will need & use. But when I go to create the IAM user and grant the permission I don't know which policy to apply.

How can I grant an IAM user specific access to its EC2 instance that user will need & use?

Comment: If your users can ssh to the instances, IAM has no effect. You need to protect the information from your OS-level.

Comment: i cannot locate information on this, do you know good article @Marcin

Comment: Its OS specific. If you are using Linux, Windows or Mac, it all depends how you setup your users in these operating systems. Its not something AWS can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also new and looking to limit access to EC2 instances this can be done with certificates. Basically create an RSA certificate for each instance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup.html

as far as IAM users as described in my original query, this cannot be done for each instance.